# Wrap a LoadingController around observables

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a problem with an old app I'm rebuilding with Angular7/Ionic4.

I'm trying to use a LoadingController to show an indicator while I'm doing calls to a remote service, but I have some troubles.

My current situation is the following. I have a `PageComponent` with a simple loading method, something like:

```
export class PageComponent {

  constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService) { }

  fillData() {
    this.itemsService.getItems().subscribe(items => {
      this.items = items;
    });
  }

}
```

The `ItemsService` is simple too:

```
export class ItemsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getItems() {
    let url = 'http://example.org/items/endpoint';

    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      map(this.buildItems.bind(this)
    );
  }

  private buildItems(items: any[]) {
    // convert remote data format to internal one
  }
}
```

Now I'd like to put a `LoadingController` between the twos, by making both the caller and the callee basically unaware of what's really happening.

So my idea is to create an intermediate service class that's called from the page class. To make it flexible enough to be used with any kind of service (I have more than `ItemsService`), I tried to pass to the intermediate class the same  `Observable` I got from the `ItemsService` like this:

(in `PageComponent`)

```
fillData() {
  this.loadingService.loadData(this.itemsService.getItems()).subscribe(items => {
    this.items = items;
  });
}
```

and I defined a new service like this:

```
export class LoadingService {

  loadData(observable: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    return observable.pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        console.log('after data received');
      })
    );
  }

}
```

This code seems to work. When I call the `fillData` in `PageComponent`, I get the observable from `ItemsService`, add a `finalize()` operator to it and finally (in `fillData()`) I subscribe the observable, having the real remote request called.

This way, if I have many services shaped like `ItemsService`, I can do

```
this.loadingService.loadData(this.service1.getData()).subscribe( /* ... */ );
this.loadingService.loadData(this.service2.getData()).subscribe( /* ... */ );
this.loadingService.loadData(this.service3.getData()).subscribe( /* ... */ );
/* ... and so on */
```

However, as soon as I add the `LoadingController` in `LoadingService`, things go weird. This is how I changed the service:

```
export class LoadingService {
  private loader = null;

  constructor(private loadingController: LoadingController) { }

  loadData(observable: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    this.openLoader();
    return observable.pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.closeLoader();
      })
    );
  }

  private async openLoader() {
    if (! this.loader) {
        this.loader = await.loadingController.create();
    }
    await this.loader.present();
  }

  private async closeLoader() {
    if (this.loader) {
      await this.loader.dismiss();
      this.loader = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Now what I get is that the loading controller actually presents the indicator and *usually* does not dismiss it after the remote call ends. Sometimes, however, I get the correct behavior: the indicator shows, the call starts, the call ends, the indicator goes away.

I'm not very confident with event-based programming in JS, so it is probably a very stupid question, but I need some help to solve this problem.

Thanks a lot,

Marco

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following loader service in couple of application which is working as expected to me.

**Loader Service**

```
private loader;
constructor(private loaderCtrl: LoadingController) {
  this.loader = null;
}

async show(message?: string) {
  if (this.loader !== null) {
    this.loader.dismiss();
    this.loader = null;
  }

  this.loader = await this.loaderCtrl.create({
    spinner: 'crescent',
    message: message ? message : 'Please wait...',
  });
  return this.loader.present();
}

hide() {
  if (this.loader !== null) {
    this.loader.dismiss();
    this.loader = null;
  }
}
```

And here is the script to call an API -

**Component ts**

```
try {
  await this.loaderSvc.show();
  this.service1.getData().subscribe((res) => {
  }, err => {
    throw "Error calling API";
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
} finally {
  this.loaderSvc.hide();
}
```

Comment: This seems quite good, but I was trying to remove any knowledge of what's happening inside my `LoaderService` from the component. In your solution, each component has to know to put the call in a `try ... catch ... finally`, with the `show()` as first call and `hide()` in the `finally` block, which I don't like very much.